# Help with newspaper shorthand

Tags: grammar

I was reading a short news article on students taking entrance exams in Japan, and it listed the number of students from the prefecture who took what test.

Here is the excerpt I had a question about:

> 、、、、受験者数は、地理歴史・公民（１）２０５１人、同（２）４８０４人、、、、

It goes on to list subjects and give the number of people taking the test.

I know `同` is used to like "the above-mentioned [blank]", usually about a group or organization, but here I think it's referencing to the subjects. I'm a little hesitant on the (1) and (2) parts.

What I *think* it says is this that 2051 people are taking the `地理{ちり}歴史{れきし}` (geography and history) and 4804 people are taking `公民{こうみん}` (civics). What I don't understand is why `地理歴史・公民` has to be broken up like it is. All the other subjects are listed individually (including separating "foreign language" and "English listening").

So my question is two-fold. A) Did I understand it correctly, and B) Why was it written like it was?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「地理歴史・公民」is a group of subjects which includes「世界史Ａ」、「世界史Ｂ」、「日本史Ａ」、「日本史Ｂ」、「地理Ａ」、「地理Ｂ」、「現代社会」、「倫理」、「政治・経済」、「倫理、政治･経済」. 

(1) and (2) show how many of these each student chose.

Comment: Woooah, that's a lot of subjects, no wonder they didn't list them all...

Comment: Is it common to abbreviate “地理歴史・公民 (1科目受験)” as “地理歴史・公民 (1)”?  If I were reading the newspaper article in question, I would not understand its meaning!

Comment: http://www.yozemi.ac.jp/nyushi/joho/12/center_henko/index.html
http://blog.livedoor.jp/dg_law/archives/51989960.html
最近変更されたようです・・

Comment: I know that they changed the system this year.  But I only saw “地理歴史・公民 (1科目受験),” and if the author of the newspaper article abbreviated it as “地理歴史・公民 (1),” it seems to me like a terrible invention by the author.  I am still unconvinced that it really means that.

Comment: 新聞のどっか端っこに（注）があるべきかもしれませんね・・・